# Adding YUM Repos With Variables

Tags: bash, shell, yum, rhel

I am trying to add a YUM repo from the command line like so

```
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/my_stable_repo.repo << EOF
[my_stable_repo]
name=Stable Repo
baseurl='https://myurl/$releasever/stable/Packages/'
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
EOF
```

However, when I do it this way and I take a look at `/etc/yum.repos.d/my_stable_repo.repo`, I do not see `$releasever` in the URL. Instead, `/etc/yum.repos.d/my_stable_repo.repo` looks like:

```
[my_stable_repo]
name=Stable Repo
baseurl='https://myurl//stable/Packages/'
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Notice that the releasever variable was deleted. I am assuming that this is because when I run the command to write the contents to the file from the shell, linux is evaluating the `$releasever` variable against the global environment, seeing that is empty, and replacing it with an empty string.

But I actually want just the string `$releasever` to be in `/etc/yum.repos.d/my_stable_repo.repo`. So the file should look like this the below instead:

```
[my_stable_repo]
name=Stable Repo
baseurl='https://myurl/$releasever/stable/Packages/'
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

How can I write the file out like this **with** the `$releasever` in plain text from the shell?

**TLDR: How can I write a string that looks like it has a variable in it (i.e. `$releasever`) to a file from the command line without actually evaluating the variable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent Bash from interpreting the dollar sign in your `cat` command, simply put the first EOF in single quotes like so:

```
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/my_stable_repo.repo << 'EOF'
[my_stable_repo]
name=Stable Repo
baseurl='https://myurl/$releasever/stable/Packages/'
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

change $ to \$,
do it like this:

```
cat > test_my_stable_repo.repo << EOF
[my_stable_repo]
name=Stable Repo
baseurl='https://myurl/\$releasever/stable/Packages/'
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
EOF
```